# Php replace unknown word

Tags: php, replace

I have that text:

```
$text = 'Some text... <a href="http://foo.bar/***">Read More</a>';
```

I need to remove this: `<a href="http://foo.bar/***">Read More</a>`.
`***` is unknown word.

Comment: how about to just cut your spring till encountering the first `<` ? Your test string is quite simple

Comment: do you want like this:- https://eval.in/785463

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ok, but how to do that? i am noob in php)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks so much!

Comment: Handling markup texts with text tools is not a trivial job. You should use the XML parser. http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php To ask a useful question, at first you should define, what is an "unknown word". This sounds like a whitelist.

Comment: @Lowder  in my example link i am removing the complete link.Do you wan't like that or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily try this function

```
<?php
str_replace(
  "The Unkown phrase  you want to remove  "   ,
  " The New Phrase eg.Space if you want to  " ,
  $yourText
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use strip_tags function

```
<?php 

$text = 'Some text... <a href="http://foo.bar/***">Read More</a>';
$text =strip_tags($text);
?>
```

Comment: That's the way to go stripping tags by builtin. However, I think this is not what the questioner is looking for. As I understand, he seems to want removing entire tags only when they contain an "unknown word" - whatever this should be. Since he does not properly explain what he exactly means, I'll give you an UV for utilizing the built nevertheless. :)